# Does a heat pump create condensate during winter?

Tags: hvac

I have a large unit attic mounted. The ac drain line produces a lot of water during the hot humid summer.  The water gets on top of a concrete walkway. I’m concerned that if condensate is produced during cold winter months the walk way may get icy. Do heat pumps produce significant condensate when heating the house or is that strictly a function of a/c?

Comment: I wonder if your attic unit primary drain is plugged up.  Usually outside is the secondary drain intended to make the homeowner notice.

Comment: @Tyson  No this is the primary drain line that causes the sidewalk to get wet.  Overflow drain lines are dry and pan in attic is dry

Comment: water condenses from atmosphere onto cold objects .... it does not condense onto warm objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, however during winter the condensate is generated at the outdoor unit (the cold end of the heat pump).

It may be piped down a drain, or drain straight onto the dirt or concrete, depending on how the unit was installed.

In summer, a heat pump will act like any other air conditioner, producing condensate at the indoor unit.

Comment: Thanks the outdoor unit is in a location where any condensate would be absorbed well. The a/c drain line from attic is the one that causes walkway to get wet. Are you saying that drain line will not be producing water in heat cycle?

Comment: @Kris -- heat pumps have condensate drain lines on both their indoor and outdoor units.  The indoor drain line produces condensate in summer (just like an A/C), while the outdoor drain line produces condensate in winter (as the heat-transfer cycle is reversed for heating operation, with the indoor and outdoor coils effectively "trading places" due to the action of the reversing valve)

Comment: Answer clarified a little.